# Break point while trying to use free() to handle a dynamic array

Tags: c

The program triggers a break point on the free() function call.

Debugging the program returns this message:

> HEAP[C_C.exe]: Heap block at 00498240 modified at 00498298 past requested size of 50
>   C_C.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I don't understand why free() triggers the break point if all seems correct...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define TRUE 1
    #define FALSE 0


    int* aloca_vetor(int control)
    {
        int *vetor;
        vetor = (int *)malloc((control * sizeof(int)));
        return vetor;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int *vetor;
        int Input[2];
        int testes;
        int control;
        int i, j, w = 0;
        scanf("%d", &testes);
        while (testes != 0)
        {
            scanf("%d%d", &Input[0], &Input[1]);
            control = ((Input[1] - Input[0]) + 2);
            vetor = aloca_vetor(control);
            if (vetor == NULL)
            {
                printf("No memory!");
            }
            for (i = 2; i < control; i++)
            {
                vetor[i] = TRUE;
            }
            for (i = 2; i < control; i++)
            {
                if (vetor[i] == TRUE)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    for (w = 0; j < (control - 1); w++)
                    {
                        j = i*i + w*i;
                        vetor[j] = FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < control; i++)
            {
                if (vetor[i] == TRUE)
                {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                }
            }
            testes--;
            free(vetor);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! Also use `stdbool.h` types/constants for boolean values. Custom `#define`s et. al. should not be used anymore.

Comment: Always check the result of `scanf`!

Comment: Please tell us the inputs you are using so that we can reproduce the problem. But for starters: `j = i*i + w*i;` Are you sure that doesn't overflow `vetor` when used as an index?

Comment: Thanks for the tips OIaf, gonna look forward to those now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem arises in this loop

```
for (w = 0; j < (control - 1); w++)
{
    j = i*i + w*i;
    vetor[j] = FALSE;
}
```

It seems that the value calculated such a way as

```
j = i*i + w*i;
```

can be greater than control.

You could rewrite the loop like

```
for (w = 0; ( j = i*i + w*i ) < (control - 1); w++)
{
    vetor[j] = FALSE;
}
```

Also in my opinion the loop

```
   while (testes != 0)
    {
        //...
        testes--;
        free(vetor);
    }
```

would be more readable if it would be rewritten the following way

```
   while ( testes-- != 0 )
   {
        //...
        free(vetor);
    }
```

or

```
   while ( testes-- )
   {
        //...
        free(vetor);
    }
```

Take into account that you wrote the program such a way that it seems nobody understands what it does.:) You should try to write programs more readable even if they are test programs.

Comment: I just did as you suggested and it worked, let's say "perfectly", but I already found another bug on the code! So let's get back coding! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`j = i*i + w*i` will become much larger than the last valid index for the array. Accesses beyond the borders of an array presents [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One effect *might* be to overwrite memory used by the hep management, so the effect will only become visible when calling `free`.